# TSQL Select from Different Table based on a CASE value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm running on SQL Server 2012.

Imagine I have 3 tables (Table1, Table2, Table3) that all have in common 2 fields (ID, WhereParam).

What would be the right way to achieve this?

```
SELECT ID FROM 
            (CASE @Var  
                WHEN "AA" THEN Table1  
                WHEN "BB" THEN Table2  
                ELSE Table3)
      WHERE "TableSelected".WhereParam = @WhereParam
```

Comment: No, you cannot do this. `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** which can return different values - it is **NOT** a flow control statement like `Switch` in C# - you cannot use `CASE` to conditionally execute code - use `IF` instead

Comment: I guess that's why I was asking what's the right way to achieve something similar :--)

Answer (score 11):

Using `IF` (the proper way)

```
IF @Var = 'AA'
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM Table1
    -- WHERE ...
END
ELSE IF @Var = 'BB'
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM Table2 
    -- WHERE ...
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM Table3  
    -- WHERE ...
END
```

Other ways (you should avoid but I'll post for reference)

Using Dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @sql = 'SELECT ID FROM ' + CASE @Var WHEN 'AA' THEN 'Table1' 
                                            WHEN 'BB' THEN 'Table2' ELSE 'Table3' END + ' -- WHERE ...'
EXEC(@sql)
```

Using `UNION`

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
WHERE @Var='AA'
-- AND ...

UNION ALL

SELECT Id
FROM Table2
WHERE @Var='BB'
-- AND ...

UNION ALL

SELECT Id
FROM Table3
WHERE @Var NOT IN('AA', 'BB')
-- AND ...
```

Comment: You should take a look at [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) It describes how to avoid the SQL injection problem you have, the need for quoting table names, and the permission problems with the dynamic sql you posted.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Strictly speaking, the answer provided doesn't have a SQL injection problem. The table names are all literals, so the SQL can't be changed by providing a harmful variable. The link you provided is still an excellent resource if this approach is to be used however.

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, you can't dynamically specify tables in static SQL. You can get the same result a couple of ways, however. The following should work:

```
Select ID from (
   Select ID, WhereParam from Table1 where @Var = 'AA'
   union all
   Select ID, WhereParam from Table2 where @Var = 'BB'
   union all
   Select ID, WhereParam from Table3 where @Var not in ('AA','BB'))
where WhereParam = @WhereParam
```

Comment: In my case, @Var represents current user's identifier. User 'AA' does not have access to Table2 & Table3 and similarly, 'BB' does not have access to Table1 & Table3 and so on.., What could be possible solution in my scenario?

Answer (score 4):

Using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT ID FROM Table1
  WHERE @Var = 'AA' and Table1.WhereParam = @WhereParam
UNION ALL
SELECT ID FROM Table2
  WHERE @Var = 'BB' and Table2.WhereParam = @WhereParam
UNION ALL
SELECT ID FROM Table3
  WHERE @Var not in ( 'AA', 'BB' ) and Table3.WhereParam = @WhereParam
```