# Pass Variable in SELECT FROM Loop

Tags: sql-server, variables, while-loop, fetch

I'm looking to select from multiple tables (MainTbl) but it will be based on the result set (StateTbl) of which tables would be pulled.

MainTables `dbo.TABLE_MO`, `dbo.TABLE_CA`, `dbo.TABLE_AL`, `dbo.TABLE_MI`

Only looking to pull based on resultset StateTbl `MO`, `CA`, `WA`

```
Declare @Loop_Count int = 0
DECLARE @State varchar(2)
DECLARE @SQL varchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT State FROM StateTbl

OPEN db_cursor

FETCH db_cursor INTO @State

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) 
BEGIN 


SET @SQL = 
'
    dbo.TABLE_'+ @State +'
'
EXEC(@SQL)

SET @Loop_Count = @Loop_Count + 1
FETCH db_cursor INTO @SQL

END
CLOSE  db_cursor
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: How is `EXEC(@SQL)` supposed to select from a table? `@SQL` will only contain the name of a table. Shouldn't you be doing `SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.TABLE_'+ @State +' '`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054854/tsql-select-from-different-table-based-on-a-case-value

Comment: You don't need a loop for this.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a loop you can leverage dynamic and the StateTbl to build your dynamic sql. Something like this.

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max) = ''

select 'select * from TABLE_' + [State] + ' UNION ALL '
from StateTbl

select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)

select @SQL
--uncomment the line below when you satisfied the dynamic sql is written the way you want it.
--exec sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: I'm getting error            Msg 537, Level 16, State 5, Line 6
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Does the query return any rows? I wrote that super fast and didn't really test it. It would definitely return that error if there are no rows returned.

Comment: It returned rows. For now I've tunred it into a store procedure and doing an insert after an execution. Anyway to turn the last variable 'AAB' from hard code and use a select list. It would still need to run record by record.                                                                                                                      INSERT #RateMeasComp EXEC spMeasRateFlo '2','AAB'

Comment: No offense but if you are stuck doing insert RBAR (row by agonizing row) you are doing something wrong. Inserts should be set based. Maybe you don't need that procedure for this.

Comment: Thanks Sean. Is there another better way to do this through SQL ? My only other option with this is the SSIS route with a foreach loop but was trying to just handle it in SQL, hence why I started with the loop route.

Comment: I don't know what your insert looks like so I can't really offer much help with that. I suspect it would not be too difficult though.

Comment: Can you tell me what this code does in your logic you supplied above? select @SQL = left(@SQL, len(@SQL) - 10)  Is it used to remove the last Union All    ?

Comment: Yes just to remove the last UNION ALL.